# Can't build apk in release version

Tags: android, lambda, android-proguard

When I deploy apk in debug version there is no warning, but when I try to build apk in release version I got this warning, please anybody help.

`Warning:com.jjf2017.activity.MainActivity$43$$Lambda$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.ArtistIDFragment$$Lambda$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.ArtistIDFragment$$Lambda$2: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.ArtistINFragment$$Lambda$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.ArtistINFragment$$Lambda$2: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.CcFragment$$Lambda$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:com.jjf2017.fragment.TicketFragment$$Lambda$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Hidden
Warning:org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 52 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
Job failed, see logs for details`

Comment: Are you using Progaurd?

Comment: No, I don't use Proguard

Answer (score 1):

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' means that
you're using proguard in release.

Try to set minifyEnabled option in your build.gradle file to false.

Like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your app still working when you make

> minifyEnabled false

then you have to dontwarn manually every warning that you have with `-dontwarn`

Exempel: `-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**`